# strip spaces from string using smarty

Tags: php, string, smarty, smarty3

I am new to smarty.

I want to know how to remove all white-space characters from a given string in Smarty?

I have a string like "this is my string".
The output should be "thisismystring".

How can I do this?

Comment: Try [`{$variable|replace:' ':''}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl).

Comment: try $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl):

```
{$YourVariable|replace:' ':''}
```

Answer (score 6):

anything between strip, all spaces will be removed.

```
 {strip}{/strip}
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, that only removes trailing spaces.

Comment: This will not do what he wants: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl

Comment: they have rtrim and ltrim in smarty http://phk.tekwire.net/demo/Smarty_xref.php5/nav.html?_functions/index.html

Comment: I don't see a reference to rtrim/ltrim in the official Smarty docs. But if they behave like trim functions usually do (remove whitespace or other chars from beginning or end) it still would not do what he wants. :P

Comment: @vanneto he wants to remove trailing spaces only

Comment: I quote: "I have a string like "this is my string". The output should be "thisismystring"." That string doesn't even have trailing spaces. Next time, read the question please.

Comment: the first comment made me confuse, i thought he is the questionnaire and he's is concerned about removing trailing spaces now! my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can strip whitespace from a variable (string) by using the [`strip` modifier](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl), and passing an empty string to it as an argument:

```php
{$myVar|strip:""}
```